# How to delete all the boxes in the hive in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am using Hive to store the data locally, but the boxes are created dynamically throughout the apps and don't know how many boxes are there in total.

I want to delete all the boxes, whether open or closed, when the user presses the `reset button`.

So far, I could delete all open boxes or the particular box but not all.

Is there is a way to do that? Or is there any way to open all the boxes at once?

Comment: Just curious why they started a project in 2019 of light-weight Key-Value database and named it also Hive??? https://github.com/hivedb

Comment: This is real Hive: https://hive.apache.org/ BTW the license does not allow to use product names...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to close all open boxes

```
Hive.close();
```

If you want to delete all currently open boxes from disk

```
Hive.deleteFromDisk();
```

Comment: That's, the point, I don't know how many boxes are there in total, but want to delete all the boxes. Actually I am storing the data on a monthly basis, and I won't know how many monthly boxes are created but when the user presses the reset option it delets all the open boxes.

Comment: If you want to delete all boxes you need to call `Hive.deleteFromDisk();` If you look at the source code you will see. https://github.com/hivedb/hive/blob/master/hive/lib/src/hive.dart

Comment: @SelimKundakçıoğlu, regarding Hive.deleteFromDisk(); will it delete all boxes or only currently open boxes? I want to delete all boxes created in app regardless of open or closed. will this be helpful in this case? Any suggestions please

Answer (score 3):

I created this extension:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

extension on HiveInterface {
  /// Get a name list of existing boxes
  FutureOr<List<String>> getNamesOfBoxes() async {
    final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var files = appDir.listSync();
    var _list = <String>[];

    files.forEach((file) {
      if (file.statSync().type == FileSystemEntityType.file 
        && p.extension(file.path).toLowerCase() == '.hive') {
        _list.add(p.basenameWithoutExtension(file.path));
      }
    });
    print('Current boxes: $_list');
    return _list;
  }
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  /// Delete existing boxes from disk
  void deleteBoxes() async {
    final _boxes = await this.getNamesOfBoxes();
    if (_boxes.isNotEmpty) _boxes.forEach((name) => this.deleteBoxFromDisk(name));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I have to keep track of the boxes by again creating the box to store all the box information, and delete the box by reading the number of boxes stored and then resetting the box info also.